# How to set the URL from an icon in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I've tried to set the URL from an icon but without success. In fact, I've been searching in OpenLayers API but I haven't seen any method to set it. In OpenLayers 2 I've seen that It's possible.

I want to be able to change the URL at any time.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, now that I understand it, there is no way to set the `src` of an icon after instantiation.  My guess would be because the creation of a `style.Icon` object is tied in to the image cache somehow.  The developers obviously thought not to duplicate that logic: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.7.0/src/ol/style/iconstyle.js#L589

This example [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/icon.html) shows you how to create an icon by referencing an image file.  Note the `data/icon.png` specified in the icon configuration is relative and resolves to `http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/data/icon.png`.  You could either use an absolute or relative url depending on what you need.

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: 'data/icon.png'
  }))
});
```

As with all other style types in OpenLayers, it is better to create a cache of styles instead of one style per feature.  An example on how to do this would be roughly as follows:

```
var styleCache = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    var data = dataSet[i];
    var style;
    if (styleCache[data.styleAttribute]) {
       styleCache[data.styleAttribute] = new ol.style.Style({ 
            image: new ol.style.Icon({ etc.. }) 
       });
    }
    style = styleCache[data.styleAttribute];
    var feature = new ol.Feature({  etc..  });
    feature.setStyle(feature);
}
```

If you need to change the style on the fly, you would just reference one of the styles in the style cache, or add a new style to the cache, then reference it. On an existing feature you can change the style using `feature.setStyle(iconStyle)`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is my question... I've been in OpenLayer 3 API and I can't to set Image source URI because there isn't a method to set it... I can be to able to set the fill, text, etc... I'm not sure if there is another method to do it.

Comment: What's stopping you from creating a new instance of the `Icon` type each time you need a new one?

Comment: I have a layer where there are multiple type of different features, So... I'd like to differentiate between each one... That's is all. Do you have any example?

Comment: I think I see where you're headed with this, not sure if my edits will help...